# Screen lock limits (GPU?) performance

Tags: nvidia, power-management, lock-screen

The other day I set off a machine learning task before leaving the office and was surprised at how little had been completed by the next morning. I kept it running for another hour and noticed it sped up as soon as I had logged in.

The following evening I left it running again but first I disabled screen lock. The next day the ML job had gone through about 5x as many steps as the previous night.

Is it possible to stop the performance from throttling when screen is locked?

I want to keep using screen lock for security and energy saving on the monitor.

This is a desktop computer. The power profile is "balanced" because for some reason "performance" doesn't show up.

Ubuntu 21.10

Comment: What “Power Mode” is the machine configured to use? This would be in Settings⇢Power. Using “Power Saver” will cycle the system down quite a bit when the screen is locked.

Comment: As i wrote, the power mode is set to "balanced", thanks